# Speed up my nested for loop in R and storing a very large data frame in excel beyond its limits

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, performance, nested-for-loop

I'm struggling to create a dataframe using the following codelines in R for complete 36 hours and more. Any suggestions to make this code faster would be admired. However, by the end, I need to store this data frame in an excel file, but I noticed that this particular code required over 300 million rows, which exceeds the typical excel sheet length. I look forward to get help in storing this in an excel (or notepad) file for future use as well.

```
library(writexl)
team_b <- 10:120
individual_b <- 1:84
team_s <- 1:250
individual_s <- 1:150

d <- data.frame()
for (i in team_b) {
  for (j in individual_b) {
    for (k in team_s) {
      for (l in individual_s) {
        sc <- l/k 
        bu <- j/i 
        sr <- l/j 
        pi <- sc/bu
        if(bu>0.7||sc>0.7||sr>6){
          c = "unrealistic"
        }
        else{
          c = "realistic"
        }
        d <- rbind(d, data.frame(i,j,k,l,sc,bu,sr,pi,c)) 
      }
    }
  }
}
colnames(d) <- c("T_b", "I_b", "T_s", "I_s", "BU", "SC", "SR", "PI", "Comment")
#View(d)

write_xlsx(d, "d.xlsx")
```

Comment: Use a txt file or csv file or something else for this... Excel is absolutely the wrong choice for that much data.

Comment: The reason behind the poor performance is including rbind inside your loop.  Binding is slow on large data structures.  It is best to preallocate the dataframe and then assign values to the existing dataframe.

Comment: @Dave2e Noted with many thanks

Comment: @BigBen I tried to write my data to a csv file and a txt file, but still the same error occurs saying that the file size is not enough. Any suggestions? I need to store 86614061 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
d <- CJ(team_b, individual_b, team_s, individual_s) # generate all combinations
setnames(d, c('i', 'j', 'k', 'l'))
d[, sc := l/k] 
d[, bu := j/i] 
d[, sr := l/j] 
d[, pi := sc/bu]
d[, c := ifelse(bu > 0.7 | sc > 0.7 | sr > 6, "unrealistic", "realistic")]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll try this and get back.

Comment: This is a perfect solution. So grateful.